# Oracle OTBI Fusion:Wanted a query to fetch last day of previous year to use in OTBI

Tags: sql, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-bi

for eg:
if current year is 2024
the query should fetch the date as 12-31-2023 i.e 31st dec 2023

select TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_Year, -1,current_date) from "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Event Real Time"
which gives me 01-10-2023
here im getting the prior year but im still lagging the last date and last month of prior year

Comment: You had originally tagged Oracle and the answer for an Oracle RDBMS would be `SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY') - INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM DUAL`. I am assuming OTBI Fusion does not support the same syntax (since Oracle RDBMS does not have a `TIMESTAMPADD` function).